# ReactJS: Return multiple list elements without wrapping element

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

This is how I'm building a simple list with react:

```
render() {
    return (
        <List>
            {
                result.map((i, index) => {
                    return (
                        <List.Item>
                            { i.title }
                        </List.Item>
                    )
                })
            }
        </List>
    )
}
```

But if there is a children array, I need those elements also added to the returned list.

```
result.map((i, index) => {
    if (i.children) {
        // return i.title and also title of children elements
    }
    return (
        <List.Item>
            { i.title }
        </List.Item>
    )
})
```

**Example**

Assume `i` looks like this:

```
[
    { title: 'one' },
    { title: 'two', children: [ { title: 'foo' }, { title: 'bar' } ] }
]
```

I need this result and I need to avoid a wrapping div element:

```
<List>
    <List.Item>one</List.Item>
    <List.Item>two</List.Item>
    <List.Item>foo</List.Item>
    <List.Item>bar</List.Item>
</List>
```

Comment: So, you obviously can't use `map` (at least, not on `result` directly). What have you tried?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Exactly this is my problem. I don't know how to get this done in a correct way. I tried to nest 'map', what is obviously wrong. I'm working on this for a few hours, but I'm new with react, so I need a hint to go on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple recursion will do the job

Try

```
parseResult(list, isParent) {
    var result = list.map(i => {

        // If there's a child, call the function again to parse it
        if (Array.isArray(i.children)) {
            //First render parent, then all child  You need to wrap them in something
            return <div key={i.title}>
                <Label className="default-label" name={i.title} onClick={this.parentEvent} />{this.parseResult(i.children)}
            </div>
        }
        if (isParent)
            return <Label key={i.title} className="default-label" name={i.title} onClick={this.parentEvent} />
        else
            return <Label key={i.title} className="default-label" name={i.title} data-child="something" onClick={this.childEvent} />
    })

    return result
}
```

And in your render method(change list with you variable)

```
{this.parseResult(list, true)}
```

Also make sure you have `childEvent()` and `parentEvent()` defined.

If you just want expand collapse feature, why not use existing libraries! Here's a good resource https://react.rocks/tag/Expand_Collapse

Comment: But would this work, if `<List.Item>` has to get different parameters depending on it is a child or not? e.g. `<List.Item onClick="{ this.parentEvent}">one</List.Item>` and `<List.Item onClick="{ this.childEvent}" data-child="something">foo</List.Item>` And how would you set the `key` value?

Comment: If I'm not missunderstanding that, the result would be `one, foo, bar` instead of `one, two, foo, bar`...

Comment: yeah! just noticed it, fixing it

Comment: What I want to achieve is, that the children are initially not visible, but if the user clicks on a element, which has children, the children are getting visible. Therefore I need some passed parameters...

Comment: answer Updated.

Comment: Hmm... I hoped to avoid the wrapping div element

Answer (score 0):

Not as elegant as using recursion but slightly easier to follow. If the item contains children push the children to the result array.

```js
const items = [
    { title: 'one'},
    { title: 'two', children: [ { title: 'foo' }, { title: 'bar' } ] },
    { title: 'three'}
];
const result = [];

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i ++) {
  result.push(items[i].title);
  if (items[i].children) {
    for (var k = 0; k < items[i].children.length; k ++) {
      result.push(items[i].children[k].title)
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I can push components? I mean `result.push(<List.Item>items[i].title</List.Item>`?

Comment: Yes, but `.map()` is more commonly used, and I'd recommend the other solution. Here's an example - https://codepen.io/brettdewoody/pen/aWrYxr